# Saving output image after performing grabcut using openCV c++ sample code

Tags: c++, image, opencv, foreground

```
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

static void help()
{
    cout << "\nThis program demonstrates GrabCut segmentation -- select an object in a region\n"
            "and then grabcut will attempt to segment it out.\n"
            "Call:\n"
            "./grabcut <image_name>\n"
        "\nSelect a rectangular area around the object you want to segment\n" <<
        "\nHot keys: \n"
        "\tESC - quit the program\n"
        "\tr - restore the original image\n"
        "\tn - next iteration\n"
        "\n"
        "\tleft mouse button - set rectangle\n"
        "\n"
        "\tCTRL+left mouse button - set GC_BGD pixels\n"
        "\tSHIFT+left mouse button - set GC_FGD pixels\n"
        "\n"
        "\tCTRL+right mouse button - set GC_PR_BGD pixels\n"
        "\tSHIFT+right mouse button - set GC_PR_FGD pixels\n" << endl;
}

const Scalar RED = Scalar(0,0,255);
const Scalar PINK = Scalar(230,130,255);
const Scalar BLUE = Scalar(255,0,0);
const Scalar LIGHTBLUE = Scalar(255,255,160);
const Scalar GREEN = Scalar(0,255,0);

const int BGD_KEY = EVENT_FLAG_CTRLKEY;
const int FGD_KEY = EVENT_FLAG_SHIFTKEY;

static void getBinMask( const Mat& comMask, Mat& binMask )
{
    if( comMask.empty() || comMask.type()!=CV_8UC1 )
        CV_Error( Error::StsBadArg, "comMask is empty or has incorrect type (not CV_8UC1)" );
    if( binMask.empty() || binMask.rows!=comMask.rows || binMask.cols!=comMask.cols )
        binMask.create( comMask.size(), CV_8UC1 );
    binMask = comMask & 1;
}

class GCApplication
{
public:
    enum{ NOT_SET = 0, IN_PROCESS = 1, SET = 2 };
    static const int radius = 2;
    static const int thickness = -1;

    void reset();
    void setImageAndWinName( const Mat& _image, const string& _winName );
    void showImage() const;
    void mouseClick( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param );
    int nextIter();
    int getIterCount() const { return iterCount; }
private:
    void setRectInMask();
    void setLblsInMask( int flags, Point p, bool isPr );

    const string* winName;
    const Mat* image;
    Mat mask;
    Mat bgdModel, fgdModel;

    uchar rectState, lblsState, prLblsState;
    bool isInitialized;

    Rect rect;
    vector<Point> fgdPxls, bgdPxls, prFgdPxls, prBgdPxls;
    int iterCount;
};

void GCApplication::reset()
{
    if( !mask.empty() )
        mask.setTo(Scalar::all(GC_BGD));
    bgdPxls.clear(); fgdPxls.clear();
    prBgdPxls.clear();  prFgdPxls.clear();

    isInitialized = false;
    rectState = NOT_SET;
    lblsState = NOT_SET;
    prLblsState = NOT_SET;
    iterCount = 0;
}

void GCApplication::setImageAndWinName( const Mat& _image, const string& _winName  )
{
    if( _image.empty() || _winName.empty() )
        return;
    image = &_image;
    winName = &_winName;
    mask.create( image->size(), CV_8UC1);
    reset();
}

void GCApplication::showImage() const
{
    if( image->empty() || winName->empty() )
        return;

    Mat res;
    Mat binMask;
    if( !isInitialized )
        image->copyTo( res );
    else
    {
        getBinMask( mask, binMask );
        image->copyTo( res, binMask );
    }

    vector<Point>::const_iterator it;
    for( it = bgdPxls.begin(); it != bgdPxls.end(); ++it )
        circle( res, *it, radius, BLUE, thickness );
    for( it = fgdPxls.begin(); it != fgdPxls.end(); ++it )
        circle( res, *it, radius, RED, thickness );
    for( it = prBgdPxls.begin(); it != prBgdPxls.end(); ++it )
        circle( res, *it, radius, LIGHTBLUE, thickness );
    for( it = prFgdPxls.begin(); it != prFgdPxls.end(); ++it )
        circle( res, *it, radius, PINK, thickness );

    if( rectState == IN_PROCESS || rectState == SET )
        rectangle( res, Point( rect.x, rect.y ), Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height ), GREEN, 2);

    imshow( *winName, res );
}

void GCApplication::setRectInMask()
{
    CV_Assert( !mask.empty() );
    mask.setTo( GC_BGD );
    rect.x = max(0, rect.x);
    rect.y = max(0, rect.y);
    rect.width = min(rect.width, image->cols-rect.x);
    rect.height = min(rect.height, image->rows-rect.y);
    (mask(rect)).setTo( Scalar(GC_PR_FGD) );
}

void GCApplication::setLblsInMask( int flags, Point p, bool isPr )
{
    vector<Point> *bpxls, *fpxls;
    uchar bvalue, fvalue;
    if( !isPr )
    {
        bpxls = &bgdPxls;
        fpxls = &fgdPxls;
        bvalue = GC_BGD;
        fvalue = GC_FGD;
    }
    else
    {
        bpxls = &prBgdPxls;
        fpxls = &prFgdPxls;
        bvalue = GC_PR_BGD;
        fvalue = GC_PR_FGD;
    }
    if( flags & BGD_KEY )
    {
        bpxls->push_back(p);
        circle( mask, p, radius, bvalue, thickness );
    }
    if( flags & FGD_KEY )
    {
        fpxls->push_back(p);
        circle( mask, p, radius, fvalue, thickness );
    }
}

void GCApplication::mouseClick( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* )
{
    // TODO add bad args check
    switch( event )
    {
    case EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN: // set rect or GC_BGD(GC_FGD) labels
        {
            bool isb = (flags & BGD_KEY) != 0,
                 isf = (flags & FGD_KEY) != 0;
            if( rectState == NOT_SET && !isb && !isf )
            {
                rectState = IN_PROCESS;
                rect = Rect( x, y, 1, 1 );
            }
            if ( (isb || isf) && rectState == SET )
                lblsState = IN_PROCESS;
        }
        break;
    case EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN: // set GC_PR_BGD(GC_PR_FGD) labels
        {
            bool isb = (flags & BGD_KEY) != 0,
                 isf = (flags & FGD_KEY) != 0;
            if ( (isb || isf) && rectState == SET )
                prLblsState = IN_PROCESS;
        }
        break;
    case EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        if( rectState == IN_PROCESS )
        {
            rect = Rect( Point(rect.x, rect.y), Point(x,y) );
            rectState = SET;
            setRectInMask();
            CV_Assert( bgdPxls.empty() && fgdPxls.empty() && prBgdPxls.empty() && prFgdPxls.empty() );
            showImage();
        }
        if( lblsState == IN_PROCESS )
        {
            setLblsInMask(flags, Point(x,y), false);
            lblsState = SET;
            showImage();
        }
        break;
    case EVENT_RBUTTONUP:
        if( prLblsState == IN_PROCESS )
        {
            setLblsInMask(flags, Point(x,y), true);
            prLblsState = SET;
            showImage();
        }
        break;
    case EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if( rectState == IN_PROCESS )
        {
            rect = Rect( Point(rect.x, rect.y), Point(x,y) );
            CV_Assert( bgdPxls.empty() && fgdPxls.empty() && prBgdPxls.empty() && prFgdPxls.empty() );
            showImage();
        }
        else if( lblsState == IN_PROCESS )
        {
            setLblsInMask(flags, Point(x,y), false);
            showImage();
        }
        else if( prLblsState == IN_PROCESS )
        {
            setLblsInMask(flags, Point(x,y), true);
            showImage();
        }
        break;
    }
}

int GCApplication::nextIter()
{
    if( isInitialized )
        grabCut( *image, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 1 );
    else
    {
        if( rectState != SET )
            return iterCount;

        if( lblsState == SET || prLblsState == SET )
            grabCut( *image, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 1, GC_INIT_WITH_MASK );
        else
            grabCut( *image, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 1, GC_INIT_WITH_RECT );

        isInitialized = true;
    }
    iterCount++;

    bgdPxls.clear(); fgdPxls.clear();
    prBgdPxls.clear(); prFgdPxls.clear();

    return iterCount;
}

GCApplication gcapp;

static void on_mouse( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param )
{
    gcapp.mouseClick( event, x, y, flags, param );
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    cv::CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv, "{help h||}{@input||}");
    if (parser.has("help"))
    {
        help();
        return 0;
    }
    string filename = parser.get<string>("@input");
    if( filename.empty() )
    {
        cout << "\nDurn, empty filename" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    Mat image = imread( filename, 1 );
    if( image.empty() )
    {
        cout << "\n Durn, couldn't read image filename " << filename << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    help();

    const string winName = "image";
    namedWindow( winName, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    setMouseCallback( winName, on_mouse, 0 );

    gcapp.setImageAndWinName( image, winName );
    gcapp.showImage();

    for(;;)
    {
        int c = waitKey(0);
        switch( (char) c )
        {
        case '\x1b':
            cout << "Exiting ..." << endl;
            goto exit_main;
        case 'r':
            cout << endl;
            gcapp.reset();
            gcapp.showImage();
            break;
        case 'n':
            int iterCount = gcapp.getIterCount();
            cout << "<" << iterCount << "... ";
            int newIterCount = gcapp.nextIter();
            if( newIterCount > iterCount )
            {
                gcapp.showImage();
                cout << iterCount << ">" << endl;
            }
            else
                cout << "rect must be determined>" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

exit_main:
    destroyWindow( winName );
    return 0;
}
```

I am new to openCV, I am trying to implement Grabcut. This is the Grabcut example code provided by openCV is samples (same as the one in OpenCV Github repo). However, if you run this code you will get the output in the same window as the input and the output image cannot be saved for post processing.

Consider the code snippet below.

```
void GCApplication::showImage() const
{
    if( image->empty() || winName->empty() )
        return;

    Mat res;
    Mat binMask;
    if( !isInitialized )
        image->copyTo( res );
    else
    {
        getBinMask( mask, binMask );
        image->copyTo( res, binMask );
    }

    vector<Point>::const_iterator it;
    for( it = bgdPxls.begin(); it != bgdPxls.end(); ++it )
        circle( res, *it, radius, BLUE, thickness );
    for( it = fgdPxls.begin(); it != fgdPxls.end(); ++it )
        circle( res, *it, radius, RED, thickness );
    for( it = prBgdPxls.begin(); it != prBgdPxls.end(); ++it )
        circle( res, *it, radius, LIGHTBLUE, thickness );
    for( it = prFgdPxls.begin(); it != prFgdPxls.end(); ++it )
        circle( res, *it, radius, PINK, thickness );

    if( rectState == IN_PROCESS || rectState == SET )
        rectangle( res, Point( rect.x, rect.y ), Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height ), GREEN, 2);

    imshow( *winName, res );
}
```

I have done the following changes for the function showImage() to return the output image, but it shows an error. How can we use imwrite to save the final output after all iterations, as the function calls are intricate and res keeps on changing. Please help!

```
 cv::Mat& GCApplication::showImage() 
        {
            if( image->empty() || winName->empty() )
                return;

            Mat res;
            Mat binMask;
            Mat output;
            if( !isInitialized )
                image->copyTo( res );
            else
            {
                getBinMask( mask, binMask );
                image->copyTo( res, binMask );
                res.copyTo(output);
                return output;
            }

            vector<Point>::const_iterator it;
            for( it = bgdPxls.begin(); it != bgdPxls.end(); ++it )
                circle( res, *it, radius, BLUE, thickness );
            for( it = fgdPxls.begin(); it != fgdPxls.end(); ++it )
                circle( res, *it, radius, RED, thickness );
            for( it = prBgdPxls.begin(); it != prBgdPxls.end(); ++it )
                circle( res, *it, radius, LIGHTBLUE, thickness );
            for( it = prFgdPxls.begin(); it != prFgdPxls.end(); ++it )
                circle( res, *it, radius, PINK, thickness );

            if( rectState == IN_PROCESS || rectState == SET )
                rectangle( res, Point( rect.x, rect.y ), Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height ), GREEN, 2);

            imshow( *winName, res );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the following line after the `imshow( *winName, res );`

```
cv::imwrite("/Users/path/to/folder/debug.png", res);
```

Make sure that the path `/Users/path/to/folder/` exists.

You were trying to `return` from a `void` function, which is not legit, either you can take this shortcut for debugging the image or if you really want to return `Mat` then you need to change the signature of methods as well.

Comment: This method is saving the image after segmentation with green rectangle still intact. I want only the foreground to generate a binary mask over the image. In the GCapplication also I have modified the showImage() function to cv::Mat& so that it can return the output, but I fail so. Can you please suggest how to do that?

Comment: Then place this line in the else block, I guided on how to save the image for debugging, it is your task to debug at the appropriate place.

Comment: Read the answer properly, other way is to return `Mat` and change the signature of the method accordingly